# My array didn't return anything in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

[image]The array $response didn't return my item from database, it produce the result empty, causing my android application to display the error: "JSONException : End of input at character 0 of". Please provide any help, i will be appreciated.

```html
<?php
 include("connection1.php");

 // connecting to db
 $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  print "Error: Connect failed: %s\n";
  exit();
 }
 
 mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
 $response = array();
  
 /* Select queries return a resultset */
 $query = "SELECT image FROM subject WHERE version = 'new'";
 
 if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
  $response = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $item = array();
   $item["image"] = $row["image"];
   array_push($response, $item);
  }

  /* close result set */
  mysqli_free_result($result);
 }
 
 echo json_encode($response);
 
 /* close connection */
 mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: so do your query return any rows from database?

Comment: @VishvaDave i try it still not work

Comment: @ArtOsi nope, it didn't return any row from my database

Comment: @JiaenOng try my answer once. copy paste it and see the output

Comment: @VishvaDave Same still empty, i have no idea why, i have been stuck at here for two days, btw i am beginner for android developing, if you need anthing , i can copy the code and paste here, thanks alot

Comment: @JiaenOng Check for this condition `$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num ==0)
{ echo "something"}`

Comment: Check your $query. To get something from database.

Comment: @JiaenOng Are you sure you have data in database. If it is there then it should definitely return. Check version=new exists

Comment: @VishvaDave i try you condition, it return empty also, i have no idea what happen

Comment: @JiaenOng Your image type is blob. change once text and add some text and then try. so we can find correct point of error

Comment: @VishvaDave it can run after i change it to varchar, why blob cant use for image? and what datatype suitable for image, because i need to display my image in listview in my apps

Comment: @JiaenOng upload your image to server and add url in the image column. then in android use picasso or glide to load the url. it will be the easy way. or if you want blob then you want to encode from php side and decode from android side a long way :)

Comment: I would try to get the name of the image. Instead.

Comment: @VishvaDave Can you provide some guide for the encode part in the php side?

Comment: @JiaenOng you can try below answers or find it on google for this. I can help only in andorid side.

Comment: @Vishva Dave i know how to decode in android side, but php i have no idea, by the way thanks a lot, i finally find the error, i will try to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   array_push($response, base64_encode($row["image"]));
}
```

You set your `$item` as array and then you try to pass it as string. Basically `$item` = string and `$item[]` = array.   So you just have to push the image value in the array you want. Try my code and give me some feedback. From what i see you made a circle out of it and got lost inside the while loop while you could just go simple.

As you will see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) array push requires the array you want to store your values (*array type*) and the values (*string type*).